# SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal, str_replace variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

so i have this variable

`$number = "1944/UN31/KEP/2017"` then i want to replace the `"/"` to `""` so i create new variable:

```
$number2 = str_replace("/","",$number) // the result would be : 1944UN31KEP2017
```

i can access my $number variable to js before using (in laravel blade):

```
onClick="doPrintTxtdaftar({{ $number}});">Print</a>
```

but when i replaced the string and the 2nd variable :

```
onClick="doPrintTxtdaftar({{ $number2}});">Print</a>
```

i got an error in my debuger saying : **SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal**

and its pointing out my 2nd varable value : **1944UN31KEP2017**

can somebody pls help me... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wrap with quotes**

Change this:

```
onClick="doPrintTxtdaftar( {{$number}} )">Print</a>
```

to:

```
onClick="doPrintTxtdaftar( '{{$number}}' )">Print</a>
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: @www.cahyonegoro.com Glade that my answer work for you...cheers mate